# Grunt uglify. How to minify and replace original file with result?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

We're using grunt for dev and prod. For dev we don't perform uglify but for prod we do. Unfortunately I can't change references to script from something like this "`script.js`" to "`script.min.js`".

I've tried grunt task like this for prod environment but it is not work:

```
// uglify
uglify: {
    options: {
        drop_console: true
    },
    componet: {
        src:  [componet.path + 'script.js'],
        dest: componet.path + 'script.js'
    },
}
```

What is the best workflow to change content "`script.js`" with uglified version?

Comment: Works in grunt-contrib-uglify v0.9.2 - just verified using your configuration. You should verify that ```componet.path + 'script.js'``` produces a valid path to the correct file and that the source file exists at the appropriate point in the build cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
uglify: {
    options: {

    },
    main: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            src: ['yourpath/**/*.js'],
            dest: ''
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different possibilities to define the grunt task, here some examples:

```
uglify: {
  options: {
    drop_console: true
  },
  componet: {
    files: [
      // map one to one
      { 'path/to/minimized01.min.js': 'path/to/source01.js' },
      { 'path/to/minimized02.min.js': 'path/to/source02.js' },
      // concat several sources into a minimized destination
      { 'path/to/minimized03and04.min.js': [ 'path/to/source03.js', 'path/to/source04.js' ]},
      // map all files in a folder, one to one into a destination
      { expand: true,
        cwd:  'path/to/a/source/folder',
        src:  [ '**/*.js', '!excludeThisFile.js' ],
        dest: 'path/to/a/destination/folder',
        ext:  'min.js' // if you want to change each extension to min.js
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And then you can run it as `grunt uglify:component`... I always set separate tasks for development and production, for development I'd suggest using uglify, without dropping console, and use `beautify` option... Even better if you use source mapping, its very useful for debugging in browsers.

Comment: looks like it standard uglify's workflow. Is it possible to completely disable uglify for dev environment?

Comment: You can define tasks which will run other tasks:
`grunt.registerTask('production',  ['clean', 'copy', 'compass:production', 'uglify']);
grunt.registerTask('development', ['clean', 'copy', 'watch']);`
and then call `grunt development` or `grunt production`...

Comment: So for example, if you do `grunt.registerTask('dev', ['copy']);` and `grunt.registerTask('prod', ['uglify']);` you can copy the source to the dest folder by `grunt dev`, and uglify it by `grunt prod`